# CSS Make parent div not fit children size

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following HTML :

```
   <div class="AnimationParent">                               
    <canvas id="canvas" width="534" height="554"></canvas>
  </div>
```

I'm setting the size of the canvas item using javascript in order to avoid scale issues in my animation... :

```
   $(window).resize(function() {
                RefreshCanvasSize();                                                        
                SetLayout();
            });               

   function RefreshCanvasSize() {
            var ParentWidth, ParentHeight;

            ParentWidth = $(".AnimationParent").width();
            ParentHeight = $(".AnimationParent").height();

            $("#canvas").prop('width', ParentWidth);
            $("#canvas").prop('height', ParentHeight);                                      
   }
```

The following code works when I'm expanding a page but not when it's shrinking. The parent div (AnimationParent) doesn't shrink.

here is the CSS for AnimationParent :

```
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
```

can anyone help please ?

Regards,

Comment: Seems to work fine? http://jsfiddle.net/7eLa2cgh/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working fine. Can you provide a fiddle explaining the problem?

Obs.: note that as soon as you run it the first time, the canvas has a fixed size, and only resizes once the browser is resized. To make it always fit the parent, you need to call `RefreshCanvasSize()` on `$(document).ready(...)` as well.

(I would add this as a comment, but this way I can provide a snippet with the code example)

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  RefreshCanvasSize();                                                        
  //SetLayout();
});               

function RefreshCanvasSize() {
  var ParentWidth, ParentHeight;

  ParentWidth = $(".AnimationParent").width();
  ParentHeight = $(".AnimationParent").height();

  $("#canvas").prop('width', ParentWidth);
  $("#canvas").prop('height', ParentHeight);
  console.log($("#canvas").prop('width'), $("#canvas").prop('height'))
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background: red;
}
.AnimationParent {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="AnimationParent">                               
  <canvas id="canvas" width="534" height="554"></canvas>
</div>
```